# How to write time to csv and read again as datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

Before I am writing to csv file i have time column as:

```
time      datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

When I am reading df from csv i am getting:

```
time       object
```

How to write and read time columns as the same type as before save process?

Befor writing proces i have:

```
    df = df.astype({'time':'datetime64[ns]'})
    mytz = get_localzone()
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] , unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(mytz)
```

How do I write to scv?

```
df.to_csv('test.csv' , index=False)
```

How do I read csv?

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

And time column looks like that:

```
0      2021-09-20 00:00:00+02:00
1      2021-09-20 01:00:00+02:00
```

Comment: simply , but complicated.

Comment: You need to separate the timezone if you would like to retain the "Europe/Berlin".  +01:00 can result in many other countries in Europe or Africa.  Or you would like to write date format with TZ abbreviation in csv?

Comment: You don't need `pd.to_datetime` after you read.  If you have +01:00 in your csv, `parse_dates` will already convert the column into tz-aware datetime.  Try printing `pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['time']).info()`  This should have tz-aware time by offset and not by locale.   Is that okay that you lose locale info?

Comment: I got response:  time    1440 non-null   object

Comment: Could you share the line of `to_csv` and then what date format is written in csv now?

Comment: Line with write and save to csv i  wrote in post. As I mentioned: before writing is datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]. After reading is object type

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use `pd.to_pickle(path)` and `pd.read_pickle(path)`, since csv cannot really store anything else than strings and numbers. With pickle, it serializes the entire DataFrame and saves it as if you had just directly dumped the python object into a file and vice versa.